# Ajax post request call doesn't work

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a problem with the my Ajax call. 
Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/sendMsg" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postSendMessage(@ModelAttribute("message") MsgParam param) {
ModelAndView result= new ModelAndView("sendMessage");
...Controller logic...
}
```

I have a form in my sendMessage.jsp that should return json. However the ajax call wouldn't work so now I am trying to get this to return html through ajax call, which should make no difference to the user. All I want to do for now is make a simple ajax call with html return.
And here is the form in my jsp:

```
<form:form id="postForm" method="POST" commandName="message" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sendMsg">
    ... input fields with path attributes...
</form:form>
```

This works as expected, so that is why omitted the logic. 
I tried adding the following script after the form:

```
<script>
        $('#postForm').submit(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                alert("ajax");
                msgData = $('#postForm').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                url: $('#postForm').action,
                type: 'POST',
                data: msgData
                });
        });
    </script>
```

So now when I try submitting the form same as before, I get the ajax alert before the ajax call popping up but the page post request is not sent and nothing happens. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Does your form elements have the "name" attribute? It happened to me a couple of times with jQuery's form serialize method.

Comment: no errors in the console..

Comment: no there s no name attribute, just the path attribute in order to bind them, which works perfectly when I dont have the script

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato OP is using Spring's `form` tag lib which automatically generates `input` elements with `name` attributes.

Comment: Please don't use alert. You can use console.log().

Comment: ah!, try adding a name attribute if you want to use the serialize. Serialize works only for "successful controls" (note on the serialize method on jQuery) from w3.org  Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set.

Comment: Where is your success/error callbacks? Add them.

Comment: as @hgoebl said, try using the console.log() method instead of the alert and log the object you are passing to ajax so you can inspect what's going on. You can do ajaxObj={url:$("#postForm").action... data:msgData}; 
console.log(ajaxObj);
$.ajax(ajaxObj,successCallback);
where successCallback will handle the response from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to inspect what you are sending and receiving:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Wait for jQuery to be loaded
$(function(){

function _submitHandler(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            //form data placeholder
            var formData={};
            //Serialize the form as an array of objects{name and value}
            var msgData = $('#postForm').serializeArray();
            //fill the formData object with name:value pairs
            //from the serialized array
            for(var i=0, l=msgData.lenght; i<l; i++){
              formData[msgData[i].name]=msgData[i].value;
            }
            //Prepare ajax Object
            var ajaxObj = {
                url: $('#postForm')[0].action,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData
            };
            //Inspect ajax object in console
            console.log("Ajax Call");
            console.log(ajaxObj);
            $.ajax(ajaxObj,function(response){
                console.log("Server Response");
                console.log(response);});
            }
$('#postForm').submit(_submitHandler);

});
</script>
```

For the URL you need to subindex the jQuery url: $('#postForm')[0].action or get the attribute url: $('#postForm').attr('action'); obviously the second one will be only the path and the first one will give you the whole URL. The for loop can be skipped if you do this:

```
$("#postForm").serializeArray().forEach(function(el){formData[el.name]=el.value});
```

the problem with the forEach is that is not supported by all the browsers**

Comment: Okay, so this is what I get event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.9.1.js:3345
Ajax Call login:30
Object {url: undefined, type: "POST", data: "sender=1&receivers=2&body=aageg"}  but it still doesnt post the page..The parameters are valid

Comment: it was just a syntax problem.. this is the output Ajax Call login:30
Object {url: "https://localhost:8443/MsgManagement/receive", type: "POST", data: "sender=1&receivers=2&body=ageg"}, which is just fine

Comment: I mean I didnt add the index the first time, but it still doesnt work

Comment: hey @user3080263, try the new edited code. from what you posted earlier the data is serialized for a GET. I missed that on the whole stuff. Hope this time it works for you :)